# Forbid docker to use specific network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to tell docker to not use some specific network when runing `docker-compose up`?

I am using some out of the box examples (`hyperledger`) and each time docker takes an address that breaks my remote connection.

```
[xxx@xxx fabric]$ docker network inspect some_network
[
    {
        "Name": "some_network",
        "Id": "xxx",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.30.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.30.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**What I would like is to tell docker (without editing the docker-compose.yaml file) to never use the network `172.30.0.0/16`**.

Answer (score 6):

When you create a network inside `docker-compose.yml`, you can specify IP range, subnet, gateway, etc. You can do it this way.

```
version: "3"

services:    
  service1:
    build: .
    ...

networks:
  default:
    subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
    ip_range: 172.28.5.0/24
    gateway: 172.28.5.254
```

To do this in the Docker daemon, you have pass `--bip` and `--fixed-cidr` parameters.

From Docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/

> `--bip=CIDR`: supply a specific IP address and netmask for the
> `docker0` bridge, using standard CIDR notation. For example:
> `192.168.1.5/24`.
>
> `--fixed-cidr=CIDR`: restrict the IP range from the `docker0` subnet,
> using standard CIDR notation. For example: `172.16.1.0/28`. This range
> must be an IPv4 range for fixed IPs, such as `10.20.0.0/16`, and must
> be a subset of the bridge IP range (docker0 or set using --bridge).
> For example, with --fixed-cidr=`192.168.1.0/25`, IPs for your
> containers will be chosen from the first half of addresses included in
> the `192.168.1.0/24` subnet.

To make this changes permanent, create or edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add options `bip` and `fixed-cidr`.

```
{
"bip": "192.168.1.5/24",
"fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.0/25"
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kstromeiraos. That is what I am doing with my files. However some tools that generates the yaml files does not provide this options. I need to say it to the docket daemon level.

Comment: I have added the fixed-cidr option: root    ps result: ...   0:02 /usr/bin/dockerd --default-ulimit nofile=1024:4096 --bip=172.0.0.1/16 --fixed-cidr=172.0.1.0/20. However  docker network inspect e2e_default returns another ip   "Config": [
                {   "Subnet": "172.2.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.2.0.1/16" ...                
exactly the same as without the option. I am missing something?

Comment: I got `Additional properties are not allowed ('ip-range', 'subnet', 'gateway' were unexpected)` error after modifying `docker-compose.yml` file. Does anyone encounter the same problem?

Comment: @Brian I think this comes from `ip-range`, to be replaced with `ip_range`; just edited the YAML code.

Comment: And just FYI regarding the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, the list of all available fields is mentioned at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file