# docker bridge connection breaks the internet

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 image through virtual box. Out of the box, it gets internet through the host OS through the NAT option of virtual box
The problem is that when I install docker-ce (version 18.03.1), it installs a brigde connection that brokes the internet

nmcli device status shows:

```
    docker0 brigde      connected   docker0
    enp0s3  ethernet    connected   Wired connection 1
    lo      loopback    unmanaged   --
```

I realized that enp0s3 and docker0 are in a different subnetwork

ifconfig shows:

```
    docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:40:2a:c5:ac  
              inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

    enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:57:af:e4  
              inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

    lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
              inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

The route -n command shows:

```
    Kernel IP routing table
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
    0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
    10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
    169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enp0s3
    172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

the docker network ls command shows:

```
    NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
    357f65a4b16e        bridge              bridge              local
    8ba7ce283fd1        host                host                local
    0aa5fcaafe8b        none                null                local
```

how can I have docker and internet working on ubuntu? I guess I need to change some config at the docker0, but network is not my specialty.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please also share output of `route -n` and `docker network ls`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now I added that output to the question

Comment: so let me understand. If you start the docker daemon, it breaks connectivity in the virtual machine? Doesn't make sense given the data you have shared.

Comment: yes, I only have internet if I do 'nmcli connection down docker0'.. but I guess that brokes docker, isn't it?

Comment: sure thing. Honestly I never seen something like this before, I'm afraid I can't help

Comment: Can you include a traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (or another internet site)? Feel free to cutoff the output at the first non-private IP. I'm curious if there's a hop in there to a 172.17.0.0 subnet. Also curious to see the `iptables -nvL`, `iptables -t nat -nvL`, and `iptables -t mangle -nvL` outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I was fighting with the same issue today and upgrading to Docker 18.05 solved the issue.
In Fedora I did it like this:

```
dnf update docker-ce --enablerepo=docker-ce-test
```

And it installed docker-ce-18.05.0.ce-3.fc27.x86_64 where the problem has gone.

In Ubuntu you can update by this command:

```
apt-get install docker-ce=18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu
```

If you don't have added Docker test repository then add it at first:

```
add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) test"
```

Comment: Thanks but after update docker to 18.05.0-ce, I still have the same problem. Did you change any config of the network?

Comment: I did not change anything else - only restarted docker daemon for sure:
systemctl restart docker.service

Comment: can you please post what do your system shows with the commands 'ifconfig' and 'route -n'? I'm sure I have something different

Comment: I don't have nothing extra in ifconfig and route -n output when compared with yours.

Try this: `docker run --rm alpine:3.7 cat /etc/resolv.conf`. If it shows `nameserver 127.0.1.1` then on the host system comment `dns=dnsmasq` line in _/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf_ with a _#_ and restart NetworkManager using `systemctl restart network-manager`

If this is not your case you can explicitly set DNS for docker like this `DOCKER_OPTS="--dns my.dns.server"`

Comment: I commented the dns line in NetworkManager.conf but the problem remains.. the only difference was that my resolv.conf has also the domain that the host OS is part of. 
can you please see the properties of your bridge with nmtui? does it have any slaves? is the IP on the same subnet than the ethernet connection (eth0 or enp0s3)? does it have any gateway?

Comment: docker0 -> no slaves, addresses 172.17.0.1/16 (different subnet then enp0s25), no gateway.

Comment: thank you, I have the same configuration. Don't know what is it :/

Comment: It seems like problem with Guest additions or VirtualBox itself. Which version of VirtualBox do you have and do you have Guest additions in virtualized Ubuntu installed in?

Comment: I'm using the version 5.2.8 of VirtualBox with the VBoxGuestAddtions of the same version in the Ubuntu VM. Which version are you using? Thanks for the willingness to help ;)

Comment: I have Docker on non-virtualized Fedora Workstation installed directly on my notebook and there was no problem but problem occurred on Fedora Server under VMware vSphere 6.5. I would try to update on latest VirtualBox 5.2.12 at first and if it also does not help then what about to try different version of Ubuntu for the VM or Debian if you need DEB based distro or CentOS or Fedora?

Comment: I think I know what makes the problem. The Windows host machine is within an active directory domain and when I used this pc outside the domain at home, the virtualized Ubuntu didn't have any network problems. Now at office, I commented the domain line I have in the resolv.conf file, also updated the virtualbox, but the problem remains here. I guess there is an issue if the host machine is within a domain

Comment: Great to hear that you know where is the problem.

Comment: I still have this issue on Ubuntu 22.04  and docker ce version 20.10.17

Answer (score 0):

[Add the name server, 8.8.8.8, to the DNS resolver](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32270#issuecomment-336772916) by editing */etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head* and adding the following. This should work across reboots.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Update the DNS resolution configuration file, */etc/resolv.conf*, by executing the following.

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

There are many issues on GitHub about this.

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36153

https://github.com/docker/libnetwork/issues/2187

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32270

https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1601

Answer (score 0):

For me, docker was messing with existing routing rules. E.g. something needed to connect to 172.20.blah (which normally takes the default route and something eventually knows where to send the traffic) but docker hijacks it with its own routing rules. It often existing LAN and VPN networks that happen to use the same address ranges. Basically it doesn't bother checking to see if a subnet is in use before blindly clobbering it - i'm actually not sure if this would be possible because the default range covers everything. Ranting asside, this worked:

1. Clean up the routes it left behind (ultimately this was the problem)

   `route -n` to see why it's broken. Then...

   ```
   sudo route del -net 172.19.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev br-5094d9589bea
   sudo route del -net 172.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev br-964b736ea39c
   ```
2. Tell it what subnet to use instead:

   - sudo service docker stop
   - sudo nano /etc/docker/daemon.json

     Add something along the lines of this:

     ```
     {
        "bip": "192.168.1.5/24",
        "fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.5/25",
        "default-address-pools":[
          {"base":"192.168.2.5/24","size":28}
        ]
     }
     ```

     See: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network
   - sudo service docker start

See also:

- [Forbid docker to use specific network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930707/forbid-docker-to-use-specific-network)
- [Problems with configuring bridge network and container CIDR in Docker 18.06 and Docker Compose 1.20.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717020/problems-with-configuring-bridge-network-and-container-cidr-in-docker-18-06-and)
- [How to configure docker to avoid a specific address or subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267221/how-to-configure-docker-to-avoid-a-specific-address-or-subnet)
- [docker doesn't use IP from defined pool when creating new networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359847/docker-doesnt-use-ip-from-defined-pool-when-creating-new-networks)