# Problems with configuring bridge network and container CIDR in Docker 18.06 and Docker Compose 1.20.0

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yaml that defines 3 networks and a daemon.json configuration that assigns a bridge IP CIDR as 192.168.1.5/24. Whenever the containers come up with docker-compose they are assigned IP addresses in a different range (which is the default CIDR and not the one I configured):

docker-compose.yaml:

```
networks:
  service:
  messaging:
  db:
```

/etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "bip": "192.168.1.5/24",
    "fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.5/25",
    "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8::/64",
    "mtu": 1500
}
```

When docker-compose brings up the container they are still on the default CIDR and not what was configured:

```
docker container inspect bfa5822460c8 | grep \"IPAddress\"
"IPAddress": "172.19.0.7",
```

And the bridge networks are also still on the default:

```
br-2b656d63cf20 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:29:9c:5f:f0  
          inet addr:172.19.0.1  Bcast:172.19.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:29ff:fe9c:5ff0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:80 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:12802 (12.8 KB)  TX bytes:7076 (7.0 KB)
```

The docker0 bridge has the correct address:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f5:75:42:ea  
          inet addr:192.168.1.5  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B
```

My question is: "How can I configure the docker daemon to setup container and bridge IP's on the network I've specified in /etc/docker/daemon.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `daemon.json` is used to [customize the default bridge network `docker0`](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#use-the-default-bridge-network) only.

By default Compose sets up a single network for your app, in your case is `br-2b656d63cf20` not `docker0`.

Here we use `ipam` configuration to specify the ip range of this app's network.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:80
  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
networks:
  # default network (not docker0) for web & db service
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.28.0.0/16
```

For more details, please check the below link.

- [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)
- [Compose file version 3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by specifying specific subnet configurations for each defined network:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
networks:
  db:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
  messaging:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.239.0/24
  service:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.16.240.0/24
```