# Docker internal network and external system to be connected are in same range i.e. 172.160.0.0/16

Tags: docker, networking, docker-network

In my current application, the containers are using 172.16.0.0/16 network to connect with other containers in the host.
Now we need to connect to an external system which is having an IP Address 172.16.2.2

While trying to connect/ping to this IP 172.16.2.2 , it is blocked saying no route to host.

So what i understand, that anything in 172.16.0.0 under a genmask of 255.255.0.0 will not get out of the external interface.

What is the easiest way to overcome this issue or do i need to change my internal docker network to use 192.168.0.0/16 range

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the internal docker network. Or if you are using docker-compose you can change the default docker network with a different subnet.

```yaml
networks:
  default:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

For the internal docker network, you can configure the default bridge network by seting parameters in the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (on linux) file, like that:

```
{
  "bip": "192.168.1.5/24",
  "fixed-cidr": "192.168.1.5/25",
  "fixed-cidr-v6": "2001:db8::/64",
  "mtu": 1500,
  "default-gateway": "10.20.1.1",
  "default-gateway-v6": "2001:db8:abcd::89",
  "dns": ["10.20.1.2","10.20.1.3"]
}
```

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#configure-the-default-bridge-network

Same answer here: [How to configure docker to avoid and specific address or subnet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267221/how-to-configure-docker-to-avoid-and-specific-address-or-subnet/63268539#63268539)

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range there's undocumented option `default-address-pools`